# delete in list via Panache in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

Here’s what I want to do

```
delete from table where id in list_of_ids
```

I know Hibernate HQL can do that

```
Long[] ids = {1L, 2L, 3L};
Query query = session.createQuery("delete from SysMenu where id in (:id)");
query.setParameterList("id", ids);
int i = query.executeUpdate();
```

But what can I do if I want to use Panache-ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `Panache`

```
Long[] ids = {1414151951951728640L, 1414152114971742208L};
List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(ids);
long rows = SysMenu.delete("id in (?1)", list);
```

Answer (score 1):

with panache you can always use a [simplified query](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#simplified-queries), something like

```
SysMenu.delete("delete from SysMenu where id in ?", ids);
```

should work (handwritten, not tested).

[Here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/4d5fc4b5467f2c7df67c2bd6b8922cbd05a6a207/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntityBase.java#L667) you can see the method definition

Comment: Thanks. Your answer reminds me. It works ```Long[] ids = {1414151951951728640L, 1414152114971742208L};
        List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(ids);
        long rows = SysMenu.delete("id in (?1)", list);```

Comment: Well, you could mark my answer as accepted or give the useful flag @JaveysWuu